# Array pointer from C to D

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, d

I'm using D and interfacing with some C libraries. As a result I have to convert D arrays to pointers for C (ex. short*). Currently I just cast them like this:

```d
int[] dArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
myCFunction(cast(int*) dArray);
```

Is this unsafe? I tried to do:

```d
myCFunction(&dArray);
```

But doing that gives the function an int[]* instead of int*. I see that in C++ some people take the first element like this:

```d
myCFunction(&dArray[0]);
```

But wouldn't that pointer only point to the first element? I am new to pointers and references as I have come from the world of Java.

How would I convert an array to a pointer so I can pass it to a C function?

Comment: Wouldn't just `myCFunction(dArray)` work?

Comment: the elements in an array are contiguous in memory, so `&dArray[0]` is indeed an address to just the first element; however, the remainder of the elements are +1, +2, etc from that offset. Furthermore, simply passing the array decomposes it to pointer to the first element. `myCFunction(dArray)` or `myCFunction(&dArray[0])` should both work

Comment: @EugeneSh. It doesn't. The compiler complains saying that myCFunction(int*) does not accept parameters myCFunction(int[]);

Comment: Is that C or D compiler which is complaining? C should not...

Comment: @yano Thank you, `&dArray[0]` does work, although the compiler does not accept `dArray` by itself.

Comment: @jython234 "wouldn't that only point to the first element"? - which is exactly the C convention on passing the arrays.

Comment: @EugeneSh. D compiler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In D, an array is actually (conceptually) this:

```
struct {
    size_t length;
    void* ptr;
};
```

The usual way of getting a pointer from an array is to use the .ptr field. In your case: `myCFunction(dArray.ptr);`

> But wouldn't that pointer only point to the first element

Because the elements are stored contiguously in memory, a pointer to the first element is all we need. We just add an offset to that pointer if we want to get the addresses of other elements.

One other point: usually if a C function wants an array pointer, it also has an argument for the array length. In most cases you can give it `dArray.length`, but sometimes it's actually asking for the size in bytes, rather than the number of elements.

Comment: Also here is a link to the spec: https://dlang.org/spec/arrays.html#array-properties